# Can I use two components in the route? How do I use?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My `App.js` file has:

```
import Categories from "components/Categories";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { Product } from "components/Product";

  <Router>
      <Route  exact path="/" component = {Product}>
          <Categories /> 
      </Route>
  </Router>
```

I can't use it this way, when I click on one of the categories, I can't get to the product component. So when I click on any category, product.js doesn't show up at all. How can I fix this situation?
(I will put all the components I used for this problem so that you can understand the code I wrote.)

My `Categories.js` component:

```
import Category from './ui/Category';
import categoryData from 'api/categories.json'
export default function Header() {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
       setTimeout(() =>setCategories (categoryData),1000)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="bg-white py-4">
           <div className="container mx-auto">
               <h3 className="text-sm font-semibold mb-3"></h3>
               <div className="grid grid-cols-10">
                   {!categories.length && 'Loading'}
                   {categories && categories.map((category, index)=>               
                       <Category key={index} category={category} />
                   )}
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My `Category.js` component child of `Categories.js` component:

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

```
export default function Category({category:{id, title, image}}) {
    return (
       
        <Link to = {`${title}`} className="flex flex-col group gap-y-2 transition hover:bg-purple-50 items-center text-center p-4">
            <img src={image} alt = {title} className="w-12 h-12 rounded border border-gray-200" />
            <span className="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 whitespace-nowrap group-hover:text-brand-color">{title}</span>
        </Link>
       
    )
}
```

My index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
 
    <App />
   
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: "Can I use two components in the route?" Wrap them in a single component?

Comment: I'm trying different things but can't I do it this way?

Comment: <Route  exact path="/">
          <Categories />
          <Product />
 </Route>

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe helpful

```
<Router>      
  <Route exact path="/" component={() => <div><Categories /><Product /></div>} />
</Router>
```

Full example app

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>React Router Example</h1>
    <ul role="nav">
      <li><Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/profile">Profile</Link></li>
    </ul>
     
    <div>
      <Route path='/dashboard' component={() => <div>Start Page</div>} />
      <Route path='/profile' component={() => <div><Dashboard /><Profile /></div>} />
    </div>
  </div>
)
 
const Dashboard = () => <h2>You are in the Dashboard</h2>
const Profile = () => <h2>You are in the Profile</h2>


ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Sorry but this way didn't work either.

Comment: i updated answer, check your component is correctly imported and exported then try again, this example correctly works

Comment: I tried different things suitable for your example but it didn't work. I think I made a little mistake or overlooked something.
But thank you I will find where I made a mistake